# change UIScrollView dragging speed

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview

I have a large UIScrollView with content, which is getting updated when user scrolls it. If scroll is not so fast, all is good, but if its speed increases, there is some lag. How can I set maximum scrolling speed or decrease its sensitivity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it can have multiple reasons--
1. are you downloading some images every time you scroll it?
2. are you showing very heavy images inside scroll view?
3. are you creating some table cell every time you scroll it ?

you should look for these reasons first and if you find one then you should thnk of its optimization.

i hope it helped in some way..!!

Comment: Optimization is not the subject of question, but thanks for your help.